# Application / Admission Form plugin

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I'm looking for a plugin that would allow tracking of an application similar to the admission forms used for colleges. Ideally, a student would be able to fill out the application and submit it (and pay, if there's a application fee) and the student could check back periodically on the status of application, i.e. Received, Under Review, Accepted / Rejected, etc.

On the Admin side of things, the applications would show up and would allow the admin to review, make notes, etc and mark the application with a new status.

Has any one seen or heard of a plugin to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using Gravity Forms, which is doing something close to what I want for this.